# One step ahead forecast out-sample accuracy and residuals

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series `my.ts` with 30 variables , and a `hts` object by `my.hts= hts(my.ts)`. The hts has just one level. I have used `auto.arima` to fit the in-sample data. What I want is the accuracy measures and residuals of one step ahead forecast in out-sample data.

I knew that in `forecast` package, there is an example illustrating this:

```
# Fit model to first few years of AirPassengers data
air.model <- Arima(window(AirPassengers,end=1956+11/12),order=c(0,1,1),
seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1),period=12),lambda=0)
plot(forecast(air.model,h=48))
lines(AirPassengers)
# Apply fitted model to later data
air.model2 <- Arima(window(AirPassengers,start=1957),model=air.model)
# Forecast accuracy measures on the log scale.
# in-sample one-step forecasts.
accuracy(air.model)
# out-of-sample one-step forecasts.
accuracy(air.model2)
# out-of-sample multi-step forecasts
accuracy(forecast(air.model,h=48,lambda=NULL),
log(window(AirPassengers,start=1957)))
```

However, I am not sure how to do this in `hts`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I was doing bottom-up forecast. My research focus is on the aggregated forecast.